# ListBox1 Left Click List Duplicates

Tags: c#

I have the following issue: Once I click on the list it duplicates, unfortunately.

The list should not duplicate when it has been clicked.

There is a refresh button for refreshing the list - this is to be used only if there is something in a specific folder.

*Code: C# .NET*

https://gyazo.com/f7d026a956c648a1ecfd1a749a7c3b77

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fakepath\Something");

    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");

    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to post your code?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you change the selected index?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to be loading the files into the listbox when the listbox is created, instead of when it is clicked? If so, use the loaded event instead of the selection changed event.

Answer (score 0):

You could clear the element each time the an item is selected:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Something\Something");

     listBox1.Items.Clear();

// etc..
```

Comment: May i get a 'if' so the listbox knows that once I click on the list it doesn't duplicate

Comment: Could you provide more insight as to what you'd like accomplished?